# (NSString *) description -- not clear on something.... (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Let's say I have two array's. Let's imagine one is a NSMutableDictionary, the other is an NSMutableArray.

I also have this defined:

```
-(NSString *) description {
    // return a human readable version of the array contents
    return self.contents;
}
```

Then, for clarity sake, I want to print an array using something like this:

```
self.descriptionOfLastFlip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Array %@",[cardsFaceUp componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

Then, of course, using that self.descriptionOfLastFlip to print something to the screen.

Ok, stupid question time... How would I define two separate description methods for dealing with the array and the dictionary in a different way? Obviously I'd probably want to access the info slightly differently, but, self.description, while it might work for the array, wouldn't work for the dictionary..

I'd love some insight on how to deal with creating a description method for multiple array's/dictionary's (or, how can you 'target' a description to one type of array, etc..?)

Comment: Are you sure you have that code? It should call itself, never returning and eventually overflowing the stack.

Comment: oops.. meant 'return self.contents'

Comment: The `description` method is meant to be used for debugging. Your implementation should return an appropriate string representation of your object. You should include any and all values you want to see when you log an instance of this class.

Comment: Without `description` I'd only be able to print the pointer to the array.. If I want to print the actual contents of the array, I'd need to implement description.

Comment: The docs for `componentsJoinedByString` say: Each element in the array must handle `description`. Doesn't sound like debug only to me..?

Comment: The output of the `description` method is not documented for most classes. It must never be relied upon for any fixed output that you may want to show to the user. If you want a specific format then you must format the output yourself.

Comment: So, how would you ever use `componentsJoinedByString:` The docs show this as an example: `NSArray *pathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"here", @"be", @"dragons", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);`  -- That would never work without `description` being defined. Guess I'm just confused about how or why you'd ever use the `componentsJoinedByString` if you couldn't specify multiple description methods....

Comment: The `NSString description` is the only `description` method you can rely on. It simply returns the string value. If you had an array of custom objects, you can still call `componentsJoinedByString` but the output won't be user friendly. Remember, the `description` method is defined in `NSObject` so every class has one. But the default implementation just shows the class name and pointer address.

Comment: How could you "have two array's… one is a NSMutableDictionary"? A dictionary is not an array (at least using the terms as they're used in ObjC). And that gets to the heart of the question: You either need to write a method that doesn't care what types it deals with, or you need to know what type you're dealing with. Anything in between makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to do things like this:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyClass { array = %@, dictionary = %@ }", someArray, someDictionary];
}
```

Replace `someArray` and `someDictionary` with whatever properties or ivars you wish to include.